# Kendo Grid Filter functionality with Server Operation True

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a kendo Grid which pulls loads of data. To increase the performance i have set the ServerOperation(true), which hits the database for each pagination click to load only 20 records each time it hits.

But, kendo Grid Filter is not working when ServerOperation(true).
Here is the code.If we make ServerOperation false, the grid retrieves all the data at once which will hit the performance. Please suggest any solution to have the filter with ServerOperation true.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ViewModel>().Name("Grid")
       .Columns(columns =>
           {
            columns.Bound(p => p.Id).Hidden();
            columns.Bound(p => p.Number).Filterable(filterable => filterable.UI("NumberFilter")).Width("150px").Locked(true);                              
             })
       .Filterable().Sortable()
       .Resizable(resizing => resizing.Columns(true))
       .Reorderable(reordering => reordering.Columns(true))
       .Pageable().Scrollable(scr => scr.Height(580))
       .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax().PageSize(20)
       .Read(read => read.Action("LoadTransaction", ControllerName.).Data("geton"))

))



public ActionResult LoadTransaction(int clientid, string id)
{
         PagingInfo gvpi = UiControls.GetGridViewPagingInfo(Request.Form);
         gvpi.FilterColumns.Add(new PagingColumn() { Name = "ClientId", Value = clientId.ToString(), IsFullTextFilter = true });
         gvpi.FilterColumns.Add(new PagingColumn() { Name = "Id", Value = Id, IsFullTextFilter = true });

         gvpi.PageSize = 20;
         var pagedResult = _contextservice.GetAllByPage(gvpi);
         return UiControls.GetGridViewDataAsJson(pagedResult.GridData, pagedResult.RecordCount);
}

function geton()
{
     var clientId = $('#ClientId').val();
     var Id = $('#Id').val();
     return { clientId: clientId, Id: divisionId }
}
```

Thanks,
Namitha

Comment: Can you post the controller method, `LoadTransaction` as well as the javascript method, `geton`?

Comment: I have added the code snippet, from controllet i am calling stored procedure to pull the data.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using the `DataSourceRequest` from Kendo?

Comment: No, I didnt use that because when DataSourceRequest was used, Filter was coming null when the next pagination button is clicked.